# sliding NSSlider blocks NSEvent monitoring for Keys and wise versa, How to catch them congruent

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

I have an `NSView` with several `NSButton` and one `NSSlider` in it.
I am watching keyCode Events with `[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:...handler:^{}]` and change the buttons appearance with `.highlighted=YES` && `NO`.

I chose this handler method because I have to act on quite unusual `event.keyCode` combinations that can not be expressed via `[NSButton setKeyEquivalent:(NSString * _Nonnull)]` and/or `[NSButton setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:(NSEventModifierFlags)]`.

All works quite well and smooth (all keys can be pressed at once, singular or in any combination) unless `NSSlider` comes into play for which i use traditional event handling with a **predefined Action** on a **Target**.

> Symptom: The Slider slides nice until I hit any Key and slides again when lifting Keys.
> Or the other way around, when I hit a Key and want to slide, the Slider just does not slide at all.

I hope i just ran into some edge case of NSResponder and NSEvent handling in general and can learn something. My goal is to be able to press any key while dragging freely with the slider at the same time.

So how can i achieve **congruent Event Handling/Executing** between Keycodes and MouseEvents of KeyEquivalent `NSButton`s and native modifierFlag changing behaviour of `NSSlider`s in one and the same NSView?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that clash.

`NSSlider` have special behaviour when <kbd>⌥</kbd> key is down.

And `[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:...handler:^{ }]` with a mask set to catch `NSEventMaskFlagsChanged` will cancel each others functionality out when the flag returns nil into the Responder chain.

The modifierFlags to step `NSSlider` up and down with its `altIncrementValue` or other special behaviour in combination with other modifierFlags can not work properly when it never reaches the NSView's action method.

Releasing the key lets the Slider slide again, Keys where useless then.
Pressing a key (specially a flag) sets the NSSlider in stepwise increment mode but its mouse events are dumped as they where not catched from LocalMonitor which was focused on KeyCode events only.

So the solution is to explicit check for `event.type == NSEventTypeLeftMouseDown` and for sure subclassing NSSlider to change this interferences with flags or to implement a different NSControl imposing as slider.

Comment: still up for better solutions, who ever friendly fellow wants to earn some points.

Comment: Even if you solve this nicely, next time some accessibility feature changes what a slider does with some key combo you have the same trouble again. I’d vote for building your own control here - maybe using a progress bar or even just a resizing view. I think that will be safest and also most appropriate and not too difficult. You can build a good looking one by lunch I’m sure.

Comment: Not sure if I love or hate pointing this out, but even "Girls who Code" can do it https://www.raywenderlich.com/7595-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-slider

Comment: did that already and runs smooth completely kicking accessibility out for good reasons, the app i am working on is in fact a virtual Octatrack so possibly the complete opposite to what accessibility is meant to solve. :-) Rays tutorials are eye candy, indeed.

Comment: Yeah my friend - your use case sounded like some AV thing with flashing lights and primary colours. I suppose you will either forever fight the OS or write plenty of your own controls. FWIW what did you base it on? Did you subclass something?

Comment: my slider is now an NSControl with SVG backing(prior 10.13) using mouseDragged,mouseDown,mouseUp methods sending Actions manually. Messuring smoothness with recording real time midi triggered from it. Pretty happy with it and a bit shoked the NSSlider was that much of a disaster control. The thing is also having full control of how classes interact when my iOS work comes into play

Comment: Nice! I'm not a heavy user but even GarageBand seems chock full of custom controls that are very lightweight, performant and that looks good.